# My Services tab disappeared from NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

Ok, this is a really bizarre and trivial problem, but I guess god himself didn't make me bright enough to cope with it on my own, so I gotta ask, how do I put "Services" tab back with tabs on the left? Currently, only visible tabs are "Files" and "Projects", I tried exploring "View" menu, but no luck.

I'm trying to get trough this tutorial, if it's relevant, but I'm stuck here.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Answer (score 11):

Window -> Services. Whenever you lose a "tab"/window, check the window Menu first.

I suspect this may have changed locations during some version, but I'm not sure. I know for version 7.3 that's where it is.

Answer (score 10):

Click `View -> Services`(**Ctrl+5**).

Comment: There is no `View -> Services` in **netbeans 8.2**. You can either use the shortcut(**Ctrl+5**) or goto `Window -> Services` to view it.

Answer (score 6):

Click Window menu under this  you can see  Services menu item  I clicked it.  It appeared nearer to  the Projects tab in NetBeans IDE 6.7.1. Shortcut key is ctl+5 .

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of adding a new post you could have edited the old one. Could you please remove the old post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

go to window tab and select reset window.... I think you have closed them...

Answer (score 1):

Click Window menu under this  you can see  Service menu item just I clicked it appeared nearer to  the Project in NetBeans IDE 6.7.1